# Android Google+ Login - Unique ID

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, unique

I try to make a Google-Login on my app!

And it works, perfectly.

But i would like to get a String or Number that is unique for User and App. So that i can Authorize it on my own Server...

My actually way is:

- Andorid connect to Google
- Google send login facts to android
- Android send login state to my server

But for the last step i ned to get an unique value like a number or String.

Thank you for your idee's

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2785485/4193263

Comment: No, i search not a Unique ID from Device. I search one returning from google+ login!

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/22/android-login-using-google/#more-157

Answer (score 0):

[Google+ profiles](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people) have one unique value with a key of `id`. This value is specific to the Google account and will never change. If you authenticate the user with the `email` scope, the profile will also contain the users email address with `type` of `account`. This can be useful to associate Google+ profiles with existing authentication systems or databases.

To get this info you would have to make a request to [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get) with a `userId` of `me` and authenticated as the current user

Comment: Okay but an unique id for this app doesn't exist like the facebook id, this is unique foreach person AND app?!

Comment: This id is not like Facebook's, all apps see the same id.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try for current **Logged In** Person like:

```
Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

System.out.println("ID:\t" + currentPerson.getId());
System.out.println("Display Name:\t" + currentPerson.getDisplayName());
System.out.println("Image URL:\t" + currentPerson.getImage().getUrl());
System.out.println("Profile URL:\t" + currentPerson.getUrl());
```

before that you must have to initialized `mGoogleApiClient`:

```
// [START create_google_api_client]
// Build GoogleApiClient with access to basic profile
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
        .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.EMAIL))
        .build();
// [END create_google_api_client]
```

[Reference Link you can Visit Here.](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people)

Thank you.